# Linq order by column, give priority to column with value

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have 3 tables,

Table `Operation`

Columns:
`idOperation int` `cdLangPrimary char(2)`

Table `Languages`

Columns:
`cdLang char(2)` `nmLang nvarchar(10)`

Table `OperationLanguages`
Columns: `idOperation int` `cdLang char(2)`

My code:

```
var jsonObject = dbContext.Operations
                .Single(o => o.idOperation == idOperation)
                .Languages
                .Select(l => new { l.cdLang, l.nmLang });
```

What I was trying to do (with no success),
is Order the Languages by a-Z, but put the `cdLangPrimary` as the first.

I know it is possible if I create a List(or Dictionary) like so:

```
var languages = new List<Languages>();
var dLanguage = operation.Languages.Single(l => l.cdLang == operation.cdLangPRIMARY);

            languages.Add(dLanguage);

            languages.AddRange(operation.Languages.Where(l => l.cdLang != dLanguage.cdLang));
```

Just wondering if there is an option to the same with linq
or in a more effective way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, the following should do it:

```
var result = dbContext.Languages
                      .Where(l => l.OperationId == idOperation)
                      .OrderByDescending(l => l.cdLang == l.Operation.cdLangPrimary)
                      .ThenBy(l => l.cdLang)
                      .Select(l => new { l.cdLang, l.nmLang });
```

If you don't have relationships set up in entity framework between an `Operation` and a `Language` then you can achieve the same result as follows:

```
var operation = dbContext.Operations
                         .SingleOrDefault(o => o.idOperation == idOperation);

if(operation != null)
{
    var result = dbContext.Languages
                          .Where(l => l.OperationId == idOperation)
                          .OrderByDescending(l => l.cdLang == operation.cdLangPrimary)
                          .ThenBy(l => l.cdLang)
                          .Select(l => new { l.cdLang, l.nmLang });
}
```